# APP_ID_MISMATCH in web engage while sending push notification

Tags: android, webengage

**Proceedings:**

- I am using push notifications to send message
- Device is getting registered in Web-Engage
- When I send a push notification to a device, Status on the console is
  seen as 'ENDED'
- Finally push notification is not received on device

**Error on Console:**

```
APP_ID_MISMATCH
```

**Manifest web-engage code:**

```
    <receiver
            android:name="com.webengage.sdk.android.WebEngagePushReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>

            <category android:name="${applicationId}"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name="com.bakmi.app.service.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <meta-data
            android:name="com.webengage.sdk.android.project_number"
            android:value="$102353245239034"/>
    <meta-data
            android:name="com.webengage.sdk.android.key"
            android:value="@string/ACCOUNT_ID"/>


    <meta-data
            android:name="com.webengage.sdk.android.auto_gcm_registration"
            android:value="true"/>
    <meta-data
            android:name="com.webengage.sdk.android.location_tracking"
            android:value="false"/>
    <meta-data
            android:name="com.webengage.sdk.android.debug"
            android:value="true"/>

    <service android:name="com.webengage.sdk.android.ExecutorService"/>
    <service android:name="com.webengage.sdk.android.EventLogService"/>

    <receiver
            android:name="com.webengage.sdk.android.WebEngageReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
            <action android:name="com.webengage.sdk.android.intent.ACTION"/>

            <category android:name="com.bakmi.loyalty"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver
            android:name="com.webengage.sdk.android.InstallTracker"
            android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**APP_ID_MISMATCH** is fired in one of the two cases:

**1.** If the package name of the receiving app is not the one to which the push was sent from our server, i.e. your app's package-name is different from the package-name entered in WebEngage dashboard.

**2.** If the GCM/FCM token to which the push was sent is not tied to the server key i.e. sever key entered in WebEngage dashboard is not from the GCM/FCM project which is integrated in the App.

Apart from this, your [FCM](https://docs.webengage.com/docs/android-fcm-integration) push integration seems to be mixed up with [GCM](https://docs.webengage.com/docs/android-gcm-integration) push integration.

It is recommended to use [FCM](https://docs.webengage.com/docs/android-fcm-integration) for push notifications and remove the following GCM related tags from your AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
<!-- remove these tags
<receiver
        android:name="com.webengage.sdk.android.WebEngagePushReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>

        <category android:name="${applicationId}"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<meta-data
        android:name="com.webengage.sdk.android.project_number"
        android:value="$102353245239034"/>

<meta-data
        android:name="com.webengage.sdk.android.auto_gcm_registration"
        android:value="true"/>
-->
```